# How to give username and password in popup window using webbrowser control

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are trying to do  a automation for a Webpage stuff using C#. our aim is to access the webpage and check/uncheck some elements. The problem is even before the page opens it gives a "Windows Security" popup asking for username & password. how can we pass the credentials in the popup window.We are using web browser control.

We have tried the basic authentication steps. We have even tried the way"
http://username:password@mysite.asp[in our case no username and only password is there]

but it did not work. I have set chrome as my default browser as IE was not able to do the above command.It was happening in Chrome. So, I made chrome as default browser.

We tried  using webkit browser control by downloading the .dll , however using webkitbrowser control we are not able to access the elements using getelementsbyId().

The Code:

```
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

    void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(objectsender,WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        bBusy = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigateToUrlSync("http://:password@192.168.0.1/RgOptions.asp");

    }
    private void NavigateToUrlSync(string url)
    {
        bBusy = true;
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate(url);


        while (bBusy)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();

       }

    }
```

please help.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0 framework. I am trying to check/uncheck checkboxes and radio buttons in this router settings page. I have that code working. But I am not able to automate the username password authentication popup dialog box. I have to manually enter that and then enter the page and do operations. I want to somehow bypass the authentication OR pass the credentails and get into the page

Comment: any solution to this you found?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following and it will work for you

```
    Uri u = new Uri("http://192.168.0.91");
    UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder(u);
    ub.UserName = "admin";
    ub.Password = "admin";
    webBrowser1.Url = ub.Uri;
```